# Dynamics CRM Online: Xrm.Page.context.client.getClient() returns "Web" when called from Outlook App

Tags: javascript, outlook, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, xrm

The Xrm.Page.context.client.getClient() function does not seem to be working correctly. When called from the desktop Outlook App, it returns "Web", instead of "Outlook" as described by the documentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334511.aspx#BKMK_getclient). Here is the code I am using (bound to form onLoad event):

```
function alertClient() {
    var client = Xrm.Page.context.client.getClient();
    Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(client);
}
```

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: Raise a ticket with Microsoft..

Answer (score 1):

Can you mention which app you use? There is two: The "Dynamics 365 for Outlook" or the "Dynamics 365 app for Outlook".

I'm not sure if nowaday this function still returns "Outlook". Now, everything runs in an iframe in Outlook. Before the add-on had a different architecture.

As a solution, maybe if you parse the url from Outlook you could find a specific parameter that would tell you the source. That's probably how Dynamics would do it anyway.

Comment: We are using the "Dynamics 365 app for Outlook".